# Locating element in Protractor when two elements having same attributes

Tags: javascript, angularjs, testing, automation, protractor

Below is the code for two input boxes, how can I locate a particular element when they are having **same attributes**?

```
<input name="inputText" ng-required="field.required" ng-change="handleEdit('First name',selectedSensor[field.key],field.key)" ng-model="selectedSensor[field.key]" ng-pattern="/^[a-z]+$/i" maxlength="100" class="ng-pristine md-input ng-empty ng-invalid ng-invalid-required ng-valid-pattern ng-valid-minlength ng-valid-maxlength ng-touched"  required="required" aria-invalid="true" style="">

<input name="inputText" ng-required="field.required"  ng-change="handleEdit('Last name',selectedSensor[field.key],field.key)"  ng-model="selectedSensor[field.key]" ng-pattern="/^[a-z]+$/i"  maxlength="100" class="ng-pristine md-input ng-empty ng-invalid ng-invalid-  required ng-valid-pattern ng-valid-minlength ng-valid-maxlength ng-touched"  required="required" aria-invalid="true" style="">
```

Comment: pls edit your code. its not visible!

Answer (score 0):

Can't see your code, but anyway the answer is simple.

Assign both of those elements to an ElementArrayFinder via `element.all` -- http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ElementArrayFinder.prototype.all

Then use `get()` to grab the appropriate element based on it's index in the ElementArrayFinder -- http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ElementArrayFinder.prototype.get

For example:

```
var userNavLinks = element.all(by.css('li.navbar-item'));
var targetLink = userNavLinks.get(2);
expect(targetLink.getText()).toEqual('My Link');
```

You could also just do it in one line: 
`element.all(by.css('li.navbar-item')).get(1).click()` etc.

Comment: is this zero indexed? so the first one would be get(0)?

Answer (score 0):

If you have control of the app under test, consider *adding meaningful id or class or custom attributes that would uniquely identify elements to ease e2e testing*.

Given what we have at the moment, you can rely on the `ng-change` attribute:

```
var firstName = $('input[ng-change*="First name"]');
var lastName = $('input[ng-change*="Last name"]');
```